# Get values from object based an attribute pattern?

Tags: javascript

I get dynamic objects like this:

```
 var myObject = {name: 'A', attribute13: x, attribute112: y, attribute4789: z};
```

The only thing I know is that all 'attribute' attributes start with the prefix 'attribute' - the suffixing figure per attribute is unknown as well as the total number of attributes associated with object.

How can I get all values for the 'attributes'? (in this case e.g. x, y and z).

Comment: use a for(var prop in myObject) {console.log(myObject [prop])} , iterates over the properties of object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check with a regular expression, which matches `attribute` at the start of the string.

```js
var myObject = { name: 'A', attribute13: 'x', attribute112: 'y', attribute4789: 'z' };

Object.keys(myObject).forEach(function (key) {
    if (key.match(/^attribute/)) {
        console.log(myObject[key]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get all properties of an Object via `Object.keys`, e.g.

```
Object.keys(myObject).filter(s => s.startsWith('attribute'))
```

To get the all the values of properties that start with 'attribute' you can use the following snippet:

```
Object.keys(myObject).filter(s => s.startsWith('attribute')).map(x => myObject[x])
```

Comment: Need to be careful with `startsWith` and browser support e.g. no IE, and native mobile is poor at the moment https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith

Answer (score 0):

Like this.`Object.values(object_name)` make an array of values of this object

```js
 var myObject = {name: 'A', attribute13: 'x', attribute112: 'y', attribute4789: 'z'};

var values = Object.values(myObject);
console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for...in` loop to iterate the attributes:

```
for (var prop in myObject) {
    if (/^attribute/.test(prop)) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for in loop might help.

Loop over keys of object test against required regex,

Example snippet.

```js
var myObject = {
  name: 'A',
  attribute13: 'x',
  attribute112: 'y',
  attribute4789: 'z'
};

for (var key in myObject) {
  if (/^(attribute)/g.test(key)) {
    console.log(myObject[key])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myObject = {name: 'A', attribute13: x, attribute112: y, attribute4789: z};
var a = [];
for (var property in myObject) {
if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
    var exclude = "attribute"
    var str = property;
    var res = str.substring(exclude.length);
    a.push(res);
}
}
console.log(a);
```